# Different dependencies for debug and release in gradle and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have an Android project, that depends on pure Java project. Both of them depend on another Java library, also in my multiproject gradle set in Android Studio. I have two versions of that library and want both Android and Java projects to depend on one of them in debug mode, and another - in release.

Is it possible for Android project? For pure Java project? How?

Answer (score 69):

Build Types (debug, release, or custom) can have their own dependencies.

To specify a dependency specific to a build type, do the following:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile "mydebugdependency"
    releaseCompile "myreleasedependency"
}
```

If your java project and android project are both using gradle, you can do the above in both of their build.gradle files.

Comment: I used `releaseCompile project(':myLib:releaseVersion')` and `debugCompile project(':myLib:debugVersion')`, but Android Studio says:

`Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'debugCompile()'!
        Possible causes could be:  
        - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
        - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
        - or there is a mistake in a build script`

Comment: Android project seems to work well, but pure Java project generates an error, stated above.

Comment: what gradle plugin (if any) are you applying to the java project?

Comment: I apply only java plugin: `apply plugin: 'java'`

Comment: You could try specifying your dependencies inside of the build type:

buildTypes {
    debug {
        dependencies {
            debugCompile "dependency"
        }
    }

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can judge from [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), java plugin doesn't support build types at all. Only android and android-library plugins do support them. I'm very sad of it. Unfortunaely, I can't convert my pure java project to an android library, because another not android project depends on it (also in my multiproject set under gradle). The only workaround, I have found, is to create another android-library project referencing the same source with pure java project: `java.srcDirs = ['../src']`

Comment: Of course, workaround, proposed above is rather unconvinient, and leads to large build scripts, like I used to have in ant (that was one of the major reasons, why I decided to move to gradle). The fact, that 'java' plugin doesn't support build types (i.e. it has only one default build type) is a pitty... I think it worth creating a feature request for gradle team. Or, may be, some more cofmortable workaround exists?

Comment: If I specify a new buildType, (i.e. beta), I can't do betaCompile "mybetadependency", is there a way to add this? In debug I want to use the debug one and in beta and release use the release one. Is that possible?

Comment: has anyone gotten this to work? My debugCompile is plainly ignored it seems.

Comment: How about if I also have flavors? I want to different dependencies such as `flavor1Debug` `flavor2Debug` `flavor1Release` `flavor2Release`

Comment: I get an error: **Could not find method debugCompile() for arguments [project ':jni-code']**.  `jni-code` is the name of my library project.

Comment: does this work with android library dependencies as well?

Comment: debugCompile is deprecated and should now be replaced with debugImplementation

Answer (score 38):

My `buildDebug` dependency was also getting ignored. My setup is the app module and a library module, and I have the need to propagate the build type from the app to the library modules, i.e., when I compile the debug type on the app I want to get the library debug type too.

As mentioned, I tried having a specific dependency for each build type on the `app gradle` file, but to no avail:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

        dependencies {
            debugCompile project(":library")
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately what did the trick for me was this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication

So, now the library dependency is managed (as usual) in the global dependencies scope in the `app gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
}
```

and had to add this to the library's gradle build file:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

This publishes all of the dependencies' build types. Note that if it takes a lot of time to compile your dependency, this solution might not be right for you.

Answer (score 7):

You are able to do this using next pattern

***build_variant_name***  **dependency_configurations** "dependency"
***build_variant_name***  **dependency_configurations** project(path: ':libName', configuration: 'build_variant_name of libName')

For example

```
dependencies {
    FreeDebugImplementation "dependency"
    PaidReleaseApi project(path: ':libName', configuration: 'release')
}
```

You can read more about
build variants - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
dependency configurations - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#new_configurations

Comment: In order to specify these Flavor+BuildType implementations, you also have to add a configurations block to your gradle file.  For example:

`configurations {
    freeDebugImplementation {}
}`

As illustrated here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies