# How Do I Stop Gradle for Android From Building *All* Library Module Build Types On Every Build?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm sure that this has been asked before, but I'm just not finding the right keywords to ferret out answers, so...

How do I stop Gradle for Android (inside or outside of Android Studio) from building *all* build types of a library module when I request to build *one* build type? IOW, if I am building `debug`, how do I prevent Gradle for Android from *also* building `release`?

---

The back-story, for those with alternative ideas:

Suppose that I have two Android Studio projects, A and B. Each has two modules: an Android library module and a demo app that depends upon that library. So, I have a total of four modules:

- A<sub>L</sub>: project A's library
- A<sub>D</sub>: project A's demo app
- B<sub>L</sub>: project B's library
- B<sub>D</sub>: project B's demo app

So long as A and B are not related, life is good.

But what if I want B<sub>L</sub> to depend upon A<sub>L</sub>?

For `release`, if I want those libraries to go in a Maven-style artifact repository, I need the `release` variant of B<sub>L</sub> to depend upon the published artifact of A<sub>L</sub>. That way, my B<sub>L</sub> POM has the right dependency info.

For `debug`, it would be ideal if B<sub>L</sub> could depend upon the working copy of A<sub>L</sub>. While setting that up is a bit hacky, I can make it work.

But then if I add stuff to A<sub>L</sub>, such as a new Java class, and I try using it from B<sub>L</sub>, I can't build. My `debug` build is perfectly fine AFAICT. However, even though I really really really don't want to do a `release` build now, Gradle for Android insists upon doing a `release` build anyway:

```
$ gradle assembleDebug
:demo:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:demo:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:demo:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:demo:checkDebugManifest
:demo:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:compileLint
:richedit:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:checkReleaseManifest
:richedit:prepareReleaseDependencies
:richedit:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:packageReleaseResources
:richedit:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:richedit:processReleaseResources
:richedit:generateReleaseSources
:richedit:compileReleaseJava
```

(where `richedit` is B<sub>L</sub> and `demo` is B<sub>D</sub> in my nomenclature above)

I am asking to assemble the `debug` build, but it still compiles the `release` build. And the `release` build cannot compile, because I am trying to have B<sub>L</sub> use new unreleased stuff from A<sub>L</sub>.

I am reasonably confident, though not 100% certain, that if Gradle for Android would just blithely ignore `release` when I am trying to build `debug`, that I would be in OK shape.

Of course, there are possible workarounds:

- I could abandon the idea that these are separate libraries and consolidate them into one. I may yet do that. But it sure feels like what I'm trying to do should be possible.
- I could not try using the A<sub>L</sub> changes until I publish a `release` A<sub>L</sub>, in which case B<sub>L</sub> can depend upon the published artifact for both `debug` and `release`. However, that seems like it will cause a lot of patchlevel churn in the A project, as my primary consumer "use case" of this new A functionality is B. Just because I have changes in A that pass instrumentation tests does not mean that they'll be what B needs, and I won't know that until I can build B with the changes in A.
- A variation on the above workaround may be `SNAPSHOT` releases, where I would somehow enable checking for `SNAPSHOT` releases for `debug` but not for `release` or something. However, the mix of Maven, Gradle, Android, and `SNAPSHOT` all seems rather under-documented, and I have no idea if it's something that I should be pursuing. And, as with the preceding bullet, this still would result in `release` being built unnecessarily; the build would just succeed in my case.

Is there some Gradle for Android setting somewhere that I am missing that says `debug` means *just* `debug`?

Comment: I am not well-versed with Gradle, so this may be utter nonsense :-|  - can you pull open the `Build Variants` panel (View > Tool Windows > Build Variants) and choose `debug` for `richedit` module?

Comment: @Vikram: That is what's there. That, in turn, means that when you go to build or run the project, it will do an `assembleDebug` task, and result in the described problems. I happen to use the command-line **`gradle assembleDebug`** task to show the Gradle transcript, but the results are the same. Thanks, though!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66805#c3

Comment: @AmrutBidri: That comment only pertains to custom build types. Right now, I am only using `debug` and `release`. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278352/535762
If you fix your problem, I would be interested to know how, because it sure isn't fully functional yet to use gradle builds with only debug in mind.

Here the essential parts:

In the "Build Variants" panel window on the left, you should see both of your modules, and next to them the current "active" variants. For instance

```
app debug 
custom_lib debug

Build > Make Project
```

Is building every module in the project in their current variant

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962 will require building the release variant of custom_lib, and so you end up building both.

Use the option that says `Make Module app`. This option will change from app to lib based on the current selection in the Project panel or based on the current editor, and will always do only what's needed to build the current module.

Comment: That indicates that my question is a duplicate. I pretty much gave up on this issue, so I do not anticipate testing whether Xav's solution is practical. Most likely it is, though it's possible that changes in Android Studio since December 2014 will impact matters. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the lack of a clear answer. I edited it to make sure everyone sees the essential parts.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962

Does Comment #35 i.e.

> Try setting this in the dependency project
>
> ```
> android {
>     publishNonDefault true
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> and this in the project that uses it
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     releaseCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'release')
>     debugCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'debug')
> }
> ```
>
> Taken from here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66805

work for you? Seems to be the one that most people think work, I haven't tried it personally yet.

Comment: Sorry, that does not change the behavior. Moreover, it would break the POM for the release build, which needs to depend upon the artifact, not some peer project. Thanks, though!