# Android Studio debugger stepping though old version of code, not up to date

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, cwac-camera

I'm new to Android dev so I may be missing something obvious that I can try.

I'm trying to debug some code but the debugger is stepping through the old version of the code, and not current version in my project.

[image: wrong debug line]
*Clearly it has skipped past my exception 'throw' and into commented code*

I have tried:

- Uninstalling the previous apk installed to the device
- Rebuild/clean
- Using Genymotion and a real device (Gingerbread)
- adb kill-server
- Restart And. Studio
- Similar questions on SO

This is actually the cwac demo v9, so it's a demo app that uses the 'camera' library, and it is in the cwac camera library project that I am debugging.

What's unclear to me is where and what is built by gradle, so I haven't 'hard cleaned' anything from Windows explorer.  I can't even check file dates...

What tips can you give me please for how to check that the latest code is going out to the device?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you have any luck?

Comment: I've found cache files at C:\Users\Jim\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1, and deleted them - as soon as I can get the debugger to connect to the emulator again, I'll find out if it makes a difference :)

Comment: @Dave ok, apparently not, even though the cache files were suspiciously old .... I will continue to bang head against wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an Android newbie and up against the complexity of the IDE/gradle (wish it were more like Visual Studio!), it was difficult for me to find the problem, but I did and it was particular to the CWAC-Camera project (fresh from GitHub).

FWIW why is it such a complex IDE/build system, it seems like a lot of this could be internalized (I mean, get gradle out of view)..?

SOLUTION

File->Project Structure->(Choose the module on the left that you run, for me it is camera-v9)->(Choose Dependencies tab)

There should be a **Maven** library entry for the CWAC camera, marked as Scope=="Release compile", and also a **Module** library, scope=="Debug compile".

I removed the Maven library entry, and changed the Module entry to scope=="Compile".  Then it worked.

So what was happening is that the Maven copy of the library was being used instead of the module.  Why?  Not sure because I would have thought that running the 'debugger' on something would necessitate 'debug' build mode.  I found this but cannot follow the accepted answer (because I don't know the IDE well enough) [Why does Gradle build my module in Release mode when the app is in Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277433/why-does-gradle-build-my-module-in-release-mode-when-the-app-is-in-debug)

I don't know if it's just a slip in the CWAC demo project, or something wrong in my setup.  Seems to me that using the Maven lib for Release could produce unexpected results (ie. customizations are gone).

Having said all of that, CWAC seems to be a life saver and am very grateful for it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Open up your app's build.gradle file, and make a change (just add white space). Then, click the "Sync Now" button in the top right corner.

I am not too sure what is going on with caching, but this seemed to fix it for me.