# Twitter Fabric +MultiDex causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, twitter, noclassdeffounderror, twitter-fabric, android-multidex

I have enable `Multidex` support in my project and it was working fine on Android 5.0 and above, But when I started testing my app with Android 4.3 and below it start giving me `NoClassDefFoundError` for `TwitterConfig`.

I can't disable my `Multidex` support. I am not getting why I am getting this issue. Tried to find out solution on net but didn't help.

Here is Exception which I am getting.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig$1
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig.<clinit>(TwitterAuthConfig.java:39)
        at MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:46)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1389)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my app.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
 }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()

  }

   android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {            
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'       
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile project(':MPChartLib')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Here is my Twitter Code in `MyApplication` class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Configure twitter using Twitter key and Secret Key
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =
            new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY,
                    TWITTER_SECRET);

    // add functionalities which we are using with Fabric
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Twitter(authConfig));

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    // especially, if you're using Facebook UI elements.

}
```

Even i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31883246/1139398) solution too but didn't help.

Any hint or reference appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
>   supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
>   performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
>   classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
>   execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
>   5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART.

That means your app would working fine on API level 21 or above.

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
>   part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
>   the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

So, Firstly making sure you have imported correct dependency, which It seems you did it.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In your manifest add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Alternative to that, If your app extends the `Application` class, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable `multidex`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

Finally, you will need to update your build.gradle file as below by adding `multiDexEnabled true` :

```
defaultConfig {  
        applicationId '{Project Name}'  
        minSdkVersion 15  
        targetSdkVersion 23  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        multiDexEnabled true  
    }
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh: Will try this solution but i didn't get you point of adding MultiDexApplication in Manifest. Can you please bit elaborate it? Thanks again.

Comment: See, when your application is having Any Class which extends Application class you can simple ignore setting this in menifest file. Now, if you are not having any Application class then you can enable its support directly from Menifest file So, Its kind of Two alternative ways you can enable the support of MultiDex

Comment: Shouldnt the MultiDex.install(getTargetContext()); be after the super() call in onCreate?

Comment: @Jalpesh https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html

Comment: There is version 1.0.2 of multidex, but using it causes an issue: "Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:multidex' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.0.2) and test app (1.0.1) differ. " . I've searched everywhere in the project for "1.0.1", and can't find it. Any reason why it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by setting fabric gradle plugin version manually to lower version '1.21.6'. Probably there was some issue with the latest one, which in my case was '1.23.0'. ([Fabric plugin version history](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml))

So I set

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'
    }
```

instead of

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
```