# BuildConfig value is incorrect

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-buildconfig

I create one android project with Android Studio and the project contains many modules.

I want to use the buildConfigField in the build.gradle file. the following is my script.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "Mode_NAME", "\"release\""
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "String", "Mode_NAME", "\"debug\""
    }
}
```

if I put these script in the app module, I can get the BuildConfig.Mode_NAME value
correctly and the value is "debug" when I click run button of the AS.

But when I put the script in the SDK module(one module of my project), I always get the "release" when I click run button.

Can you help me to resolve this issue ? Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277433/why-does-gradle-build-my-module-in-release-mode-when-the-app-is-in-debug   similar faq may help u

Comment: Have you find the solution to this? I've encountered very similar problem