# How to add a directory inside a package?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project here, that consists of native parts (`*.cpp` and `*.h` files) within the `jni` folder. In this, there is a package called `modules` that has several directories in it. I'd like to add my own module in the `modules` package with another sub-directory, however I can only add packages:

[image: Adding a package to a package in Android Studio]

Since I believe Android Studio limits me on that point, **I added the folder outside of Android Studio, removed my `.idea` folder and the `*.iml` files and re-synced Gradle.** However, my new folder is still a package (icon like the module folder) and not a simple sub-directory like the other directories:

[image: Added folder becomes a package after Gradle sync]

I hope I got the terminology right and don't lack enough understanding about packages and directories. De facto, the other directories are correct, but I could not find anything within the Gradle files that would explain this behaviour.

Here is the `build.gradle` of the lib:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    // If you want to use the debugger for JNI code, you want to compile this lib-project in Debug!
    // And due to gradle limitations/bugs, the best way is to always compile it in debug.
    // See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962
    // and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277433/why-does-gradle-build-my-module-in-release-mode-when-the-app-is-in-debug
    // defaultPublishConfig "debug"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "-j2"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs('src/main/java', 'src/jni/SDL2-2.0.5/android-project/src')
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.arr'])
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
}
```

And the `build.gradle` of the whole project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I added my new files in my new folder to the `Android.mk` like the other files were added.

How can I add a directory instead of a package to that `modules` folder?

Further information: This is the Android port of the LÖVE (love2d) game framework. I'm using a Mac.

Comment: @cricket_007 As I said in my question already, I tried this, and it's still added as package.

Comment: What if you copied one of the other directories, then cleaned out all the files in it?

Comment: Copying a folder with a new name results in a package, too. I need to know how Gradle comes to the decision that those folders are directories instead of packages to be able to tell Gradle to do the same with my new folder.

Comment: Is this project under public source control? If yes, could you add a link? I guess the root of your problem is caused by another file, so I would like to check the whole project structure (maybe even test on my own system).

Comment: Why do you want to create a "folder" in the first place? If it's for storing non-java files, then you should move the files to the `res` folder. The `src` folder should *only* contain source code

Comment: @lu.koerfer Yes it is. This is my fork containing the problem: https://bitbucket.org/MartyMaro/love2d-admob-unityads-inappbilling-gameservices-android/src/master/ and this is the original repo: https://bitbucket.org/MartinFelis/love-android-sdl2/src/master/ my own fork cannot compile, because some files are not converted from iOS yet, but it should help to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @vatbub I want to create a directory, not folder (different in AS) and I want to do it, because I want to add a new module to this framework. I didn't create the other stuff and to stay aligned with the rest I want to do the same like the original programmer of the port. Cpp and h files are native source files, why exactly should they be located in the res folder at all? As I understand they need to be located within the jni folder at least.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that the issue is gone when the repo is pulled to a clean folder without other files. It seems I forgot to remove any file that causes the issue allowing me to recognise the folder as directory. I still want to know why this is happening, though. You can reproduce the issue by trying to add another directory to the folder. The folder is at: `/love/src/jni/love/src/module`

Comment: @modiX, Sry, I forgot about your C++ files, they should obviously reside in the `jni` folder. What I was talking about were resource files like images or xml files which are not source code